# Spring Data can't autowire repository in the test

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-data

I've just started to learn spring-data and I've problem with autowire repository in the test class

I created simple maven structure

```
-src
--main
---java
----org.task.planner
-----config
-----entity
-----repository
-----service
--test
----org.task.planner
```

with configuration class in the(main/java/org/task/planner/config) which works correctly

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.task.planner")
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.task.planner.repository")
public class DataConfig {...}
```

in the repository package was created TaskRepository

```
public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
    Task findByName(String name);
}
```

And I checked that this bean has been instantiated an can be obtained from context

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataConfig.class);
    TaskRepository taskRepository = (TaskRepository) context.getBean("taskRepository");
    Task byName = taskRepository.findByName("someName");
}
```

but in the test class (which located in the test package) intellij idea gives warning "Could not autowire. No beans of 'TaskRepository' type found", but test works fine...

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = DataConfig.class)
    public class TaskRepositoryTest {

        @Autowired
        private TaskRepository taskRepository;

        @Test
        public void shouldCreateTaskWithoutSubTask() {
            Task task = taskRepository.findByName("someName");
            assertEquals("description", task.getDescription());
        }
    }
```

this problem can be solved using @Repository annotation, like this:

```
    @Repository
    public interface TaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long> {
        Task findByName(String name);
    }
```

I can't get it, did I configure something incorrectly and should add annotation @Repository or idea gives wrong warning? (As far as I remember, this annotation used for custom repository)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to have declared @Repository annotation. However, Custom repository also will in directly uses JpaRepository. So, Whenever you gotta use JpaRepository has to be declared with @Repository annotation.

Upon this declaration, Spring can be scanned the appropirate component  can wired them through autowire or setter wire.

Answer (score 0):

your `DataConfig.class` anotate with

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
@ComponentScan("org.task.planner.repository")
```

and add `TaskRepositoryTest.class`  `@Transactional` anatation also you make all repository class anotate with `@Repository` anotation